# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found (innerjoin in laravel)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need to retrieve quizzes from the database( for every questions in quiz there is a column in quizItem table that has quiz_id,question_id,option_id ). Now I'm trying to retrieve all questions with options that were used in the quiz.

My sql query:

```
  $quizzes = quiz::with('User','user_info','company','quizItem')
    ->join('questions','quiz_items.question_id','=','questions.id')
    ->join('options','options.question_id','=','questions.id')
    ->where([
    ['quizzes.finished', '=', '0'],
  ])
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
```

When i try to load the view I get an error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'quiz_items.question_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `quizzes`
> inner join `questions` on `questions`.`id` =
> `quiz_items`.`question_id` where (`quizzes`.`finished` = 0) order by
> `created_at` desc)

Am I even doing this the right way?

QuizItem table: (quiz_items) -- table name
[image: QuizItem_table]

Comment: QuizItem or quiz_items? you are referring to two different table names

Comment: quizItem is the model's name (I've got an eloquent relationship with the quiz - quizItem). table name for quizItem is "quiz_items"

Comment: Shouldn't there be any `JOIN` on that table `quiz_items` in your query?

Comment: You should not use `join` when using eloquent models. You should be using `with`(as you are) and if you need to filter by a related model you should use `whereHas`. laravel will use the correct join conditions for you in this case

Comment: @apokryfos okay. but how would I get the question and all the options for every quizItem with whereHas? do i need to add question model and option model to the query? and setup eloquent relationship with quiz and both models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not confuse Laravel Eloquent's query builder `with()` method, used for [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), with actual SQL joins. `with()` is an (optional) optimization needed only if you expected to load several objects at the same time and you plan to use its related models.

If you have properly defined [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships) methods in your model, you can access all its related objects as properties. Laravel will take care of all the needed subqueries.

At first looks like your 'Quiz' model should have relationships 'user', 'company' and 'items'. Your 'QuizItem' model would have an 'options' relationship and 'User' a 'UserInfo' relationship.

The query would than become simply:

```
$quizzes = Quiz::where('finished', '0')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: when I dd($quizzes) I do not see any relationships. How do i access them? Can you give me an example. Thanks

Comment: You must define them yourself in your model's code first.

See https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships